# SharePoint 2013 search does not find specific document

Tags: search

I am using Sharepoint 2013

in a library i Have 2  PDF documents with names
"Archiving" and
"Archiving - manual"

The problem is that I don't find an explanation for 
- When I search with key word Archiving it finds the document Archiving but not the document  "Archiving - manual"

- only when I search for example with "archiving man" it finds the document
- It seams unlogical since I can only find the document when i "narrow" the search criteria

anyone who can explain this ? 
thanks
Tom.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the search word breaker. The hyphen prevents the words from being broken apart and searched on.

[Searching hyphenated words problem in SharePoint](http://www.getsharepointsolutions.com/searching-hyphenated-words-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly Steven correctly pointed out my point here to notice is we would need to understand how KQL works.

That will help us Form the search query to get desired results